# CSS3 :first-letter works in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

Just as the title would suggest, when I use the `p:first-letter` selector, it works fine in Chrome but doesn't apply to some paragraphs in Firefox.

Here's the code (using SASS) that I use to apply the style:

```
p:first-letter
    font-family: 'Medici Text', serif
    float: left
    font-size: 5em
    line-height: 60px
    padding: 4px 8px 0 3px

.of-gods
        &:before
            content: ""
            width: 400px
            height: 400px
            @include absolute-center
            background: url("../../images/vectors/RopeBorder.svg") no-repeat center center
            background-size: contain
            animation: rotate-cw 20s linear infinite

        &:after
            content: ""
            width: 150px
            height: 250px
            @include absolute-center
            background: url("../../images/vectors/fist.svg") no-repeat center center
            background-size: contain
```

Here's an image of what it looks like in Chrome:
[Drop caps in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlOcu.png)

This is what it looks like in Firefox:
[Lack of drops caps in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h4Bh.png)

For what it's worth, the paragraph in question uses `:before` and `:after` elements. I've seen something concerning those when I researched the question, but the only thing I've seen was a bug report dated to 2003 that was supposedly fixed, about `:first-letter` not working when either `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements are styled.

**EDIT:** Apologies for forgetting to include an online example. [Here's what I'm working with currently.](https://jsfiddle.net/99sLmnnr/) HTML is compiled from Jade.

**EDIT #2:** Added more SASS code to illustrate what the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements look like.

Comment: That code works fine in firefox. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJvgjj. Please create a minimal, complete, verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: While images are good to *see* the problem, we need the actual code or a demo to debug it. In this case, I don't think the CSS alone is sufficient to debug. Please include your HTML also or create a demo.

Comment: Can you try to wrap the p in a div and then try? Reference from a different users fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/X8y2r/2/

Comment: I ran [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gLvyamht/) in Firefox and the dropcap worked fine. Could it be that your font choice isn't in your HTML code? The `Medici Text`?

Comment: The `Medici Text` is a custom @font-face rule that works well in both Firefox and Chrome. After some testing, I've come to the conclusion that Firefox is having these issues because both my :after and :before elements have `content: ""` and a background image. Chrome doesn't seem to mind that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see <strike>2</strike> 3 choices for you

1: Move the `before`/`after` pseudo classes to the parent, `choices`

```
.choices:before {
        content: "";
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        /*@include absolute-center;*/
        background: url("../../images/vectors/RopeBorder.svg") no-repeat center center;
        background-size: contain;
        animation: rotate-cw 20s linear infinite;
}
.choices:after {
        content: "";
        width: 150px;
        height: 250px;
        /*@include absolute-center*/
        background: url("../../images/vectors/fist.svg") no-repeat center center;
        background-size: contain;
}
```

Sample

```css
p:first-letter {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
  float: left;
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 4px 8px 0 3px;
}
.choices:before {
            content: "";
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            /*@include absolute-center;*/
            background: url("../../images/vectors/RopeBorder.svg") no-repeat center center;
            background-size: contain;
            animation: rotate-cw 20s linear infinite;
}
.choices:after {
            content: "";
            width: 150px;
            height: 250px;
            /*@include absolute-center*/
            background: url("../../images/vectors/fist.svg") no-repeat center center;
            background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">
  <p class="of-gods">
    The land yearns for salvation. Wars, pestilence. Famine, death. As far as the eye can see, suffering and sorrow rule with an iron grasp. We were warned. Yet we would not listen. In our hubris, the prophetic words of the blind brothers fell on our deaf
    ears. We must seek salvation. The four Gods will guide us. Since time immemorial, before the four races strode across these lands, they have kept vigil eternal and unyielding. In them we shall find solace. In them there is peace.
  </p>
</div>
```

2: Add an extra wrapper and set the the `before`/`after` pseudo classes on it *(added this version based on a comment)*

```
.choices div:before {
        content: "";
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        /*@include absolute-center;*/
        background: url("../../images/vectors/RopeBorder.svg") no-repeat center center;
        background-size: contain;
        animation: rotate-cw 20s linear infinite;
}
.choices div:after {
        content: "";
        width: 150px;
        height: 250px;
        /*@include absolute-center*/
        background: url("../../images/vectors/fist.svg") no-repeat center center;
        background-size: contain;
}
```

Sample

```css
p:first-letter {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
  float: left;
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 4px 8px 0 3px;
}
.choices div:before {
            content: "";
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            /*@include absolute-center;*/
            background: url("../../images/vectors/RopeBorder.svg") no-repeat center center;
            background-size: contain;
            animation: rotate-cw 20s linear infinite;
}
.choices div:after {
            content: "";
            width: 150px;
            height: 250px;
            /*@include absolute-center*/
            background: url("../../images/vectors/fist.svg") no-repeat center center;
            background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">
  <div><p class="of-gods">
    The land yearns for salvation. Wars, pestilence. Famine, death. As far as the eye can see, suffering and sorrow rule with an iron grasp. We were warned. Yet we would not listen. In our hubris, the prophetic words of the blind brothers fell on our deaf
    ears. We must seek salvation. The four Gods will guide us. Since time immemorial, before the four races strode across these lands, they have kept vigil eternal and unyielding. In them we shall find solace. In them there is peace.
  </p></div>
</div>
```

3: Move the first letter `T` to the `before` pseudo class's content

```
.of-gods:before {
        content: "T";
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        /*@include absolute-center;*/
        background: url("../../images/vectors/RopeBorder.svg") no-repeat center center;
        background-size: contain;
        animation: rotate-cw 20s linear infinite;
}
```

Sample

```css
p:first-letter {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
  float: left;
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 4px 8px 0 3px;
}
.of-gods:before {
            content: "T";
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            /*@include absolute-center;*/
            background: url("../../images/vectors/RopeBorder.svg") no-repeat center center;
            background-size: contain;
            animation: rotate-cw 20s linear infinite;
}
.of-gods:after {
            content: "";
            width: 150px;
            height: 250px;
            /*@include absolute-center*/
            background: url("../../images/vectors/fist.svg") no-repeat center center;
            background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">
  <p class="of-gods">
    he land yearns for salvation. Wars, pestilence. Famine, death. As far as the eye can see, suffering and sorrow rule with an iron grasp. We were warned. Yet we would not listen. In our hubris, the prophetic words of the blind brothers fell on our deaf
    ears. We must seek salvation. The four Gods will guide us. Since time immemorial, before the four races strode across these lands, they have kept vigil eternal and unyielding. In them we shall find solace. In them there is peace.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I modified your first answer by wrapping the paragraph in another div and then styling that div's `:before` and `:after`. That solves the problem.

Comment: @MorinoAndo Thanks, and yes, that is another way to avoid the pseudo element interfere with first-letter class

Comment: I should probably clarify that I did what I did because I have another paragraph styled the same way, wrapped in the same `<div class="choices">` segment. If anyone is interested, [this is what it looks like ultimately.](http://imgur.com/a/i6ES8)

Comment: @MorinoAndo Updated my answer with such sample